# Можно ли использовать переменную, созданную в одном блоке try-catch, в другом блоке try-catch

Tags: java

Есть метод, который ищет минимальное значение в массиве `ArrayList` типа `String`, в котором присутствует некоторое количество мусора, то есть не все элементы могут быть приведены к нужному типу (`double`). Решил для себя этот вопрос с помощью конструкции `try{} catch{}` в теле цикла. Но, пока не понял как зацепить первоначальную переменную из массива, с которой я в дальнейшем сравниваю остальные элементы массива. Eсли брать первый/нулевой/производный индекс — можно нарваться на parse exception, а если поместить код поиска исходной переменной в `try - catch` - полученную переменную не видит основной блок, также помещенный в `try - catch.`

Пока я решил для себя проблему тем, что первоначально просто присвоил переменной `min` очень большое число, наверняка большее, того что может встретиться в моем массиве. Но это не красиво и совсем не гибко.

Догадываюсь, что можно написать отдельный метод для поиска произвольного числа в массиве, но, возможно, есть более простое решение?

```
public static double min(ArrayList<String> data)
{
//double min = 100000;
try {
for(String x : data) {
Double min = Double.parseDouble(x.replaceAll(" ","").replace(",",".")); //переменная min в этом блоке, не видима в следующем блоке
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{       
}

for (String x : data) {
try {
if (Double.parseDouble(x.replaceAll(" ","").replace(",",".")) < min)
min = Double.parseDouble(x.replaceAll(" ","").replace(",","."));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
//System.out.println("Parsing error");
continue;
}
}
return min;
}
```

Comment: Переменная, объявленая в блоке видна только в этом блоке. Чтобы она была видна в двух блоках try{}catch(){} она должна быть объявлена перед ними

Comment: Я бы выделил отдельную функцию `Double GetDoubleOrNull(String s) { try { return Double.parseDouble(x.replaceAll(" ","").replace(",",".")); } catch { return null; } }`, с ней код стал бы намного обозримее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

объявите

```
Double min = null;
```

до первого блока `try{}catch(){}`

тогда она будет видна во втором

**UPD**

Или даже так:

```
Double min = null;
for(String x : data) {
   if(min == null){
      try{
         min = Double.parseDouble(x.replaceAll(" ","").replace(",",".")); 
      }catch(Exception e){
      }
   }else{
      try {
         Double parsed = Double.parseDouble(x.replaceAll(" ","").replace(",","."));
         if (parsed < min)
            min = parsed;
      }catch(Exception e){
      }
   }
}
```

**UPD 2**
А вот так еще симпотичнее:

```
Double min = null;
for(String x : data) {
    Double parsed = null;
    try {
        parsed = Double.parseDouble(x.replaceAll(" ","").replace(",","."));
    }catch(Exception e){
        continue;
    }
    if(min == null){
        min = parsed; 
    }else if (parsed < min){
        min = parsed;
    }
}
```